# Proof Continuity of Power Functions

Tags: proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove:

$$\lim_{x\to c}Ax^k=Ac^k.$$

What I have:

For $k > 0$

For all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x−c|<\delta$ implies $|Ax^k−Ac^k|<\varepsilon$

$|Ax^k−Ac^k|=|A||x^k−c^k|<|A||(\delta-c)^k−c^k|=k.root((((|A||\varepsilon^k−c^k|)/|A|)+c^k))=\varepsilon$

I have doubts that I did this correctly.

Comment: your last equality is incorrect.

Comment: Do you actually want (or need to) prove this using nothing but the (epsilon delta) definition?

Comment: You can do this in steps: 1. Show that a power series is continuous. 2. Show that exponentiation, defined by a power series, converges everywhere. 3. Re-write this limit using exponentiation ($Ax^k = Ae^{k \log x}$)

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ is an integer,
you can
use
$x^k-c^k
=(x-c)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}x^jc^{k-1-j}
$,
let
$x \to c$,
and bound the sum.

Answer (score 0):

you've noted $k>0$,

you could always Assume it is continuous and if you're wrong you should come to a contradiction.

then use tailors as a linear approximation.
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{f^{i}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^{i}+\frac{r_k(x)}{k!}(x-a)^k$$
this gives
$$Ax^{k}=Ac^{k}+Akc^{k-1}\frac{x-c}{1!}+...$$
$$Lim_{x\rightarrow c}Ax^k = lim_{x \rightarrow c} (Ac^{k}+Akc^{k-1}\frac{x-c}{1!}+...)$$
$$Lim_{x \rightarrow c}Ax^k=Ac^k$$ as req

Comment: You are assuming a lot. Also, your n should be k.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would we show this directly:

$$\lim_{x\to c}Ax^k=Ac^k.$$

Notice that $\lim_{x\to c}Ax^k$ is just $(\lim_{x\to c}x) * (\lim_{x\to c}x)*(\lim_{x\to c}x) \dots \text{ k times, and we can do this because it's the product rule = $x^k$}$

So we can say that: $\lim_{x\to c}Ax^k$ is just $(\lim_{x\to c}x) * (\lim_{x\to c}x)*(\lim_{x\to c}x) \dots = c*c*c \dots \text{ this goes k times = $c^k$}$

Then we know from constant limit, that we can just add our constant $A$.

Using epsilon-delta is kinda hard for this example.